# React Bootstrap Accordeon iterating through map

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to create accordeon.
Why my Accordeon doesn't work. It doesn't collapse, or slides down, it doesn't react on my clicks at all!
Here is simplified version of my problem:
Html:

```
<div class="container" id="app">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var Accordion = ReactBootstrap.Accordion;
var Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;

var AcEntry = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <Panel header={this.props.name} eventKey={this.props.id}>
        {this.props.text}
      </Panel>
      )
  }
});


var App = React.createClass({
  render(){
    var entries=[
      {id:1, name: "first entry", text:"first sample text"},
      {id:2, name: "second entry", text:"second sample text"}
    ];
    return (
      <Accordion>    
        {entries.map(function(entry){
          return <AcEntry name={entry.name} id={entry.id} text={entry.text} />
        })}
      </Accordion>    
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I know this problem was mentioned before [react-bootstrap Accordion not collapsing with map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906086/react-bootstrap-accordion-not-collapsing-with-map)
But the provided solution is terribly ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `eventKey` prop at `AcEntry` level and pass all `props` of `AcEntry` components through `Panel` in order to make `Accordion` work properly.You can fix your code like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwwyQX?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
var Button=ReactBootstrap.Button;
var Accordion = ReactBootstrap.Accordion;
var Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;

var AcEntry = React.createClass({
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {this.props.text}
    </div>
    )
}
});


var App = React.createClass({
render(){
  var entries=[
    {id:1, name: "first entry", text:"first sample text"},
    {id:2, name: "second entry", text:"second sample text"}
  ];
  //Do not wrap Panel by anything in your map!
  return (
    <Accordion>    
      {entries.map((entry)=>(
        <Panel header={entry.name} eventKey={entry.id}>
          <AcEntry text={entry.text}/>
        </Panel>))}
    </Accordion>    
  )
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

So only one note:
Do not wrap Panel by anything in your map!